# Assigning specific type object into an generic array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics, casting

I have a generic type called `Vector<T>`, I created it as so, cause the `T` might be `float` or `Complex` :

```
public class Vector<T>
    {
        #region Properties
        public ulong Length
        {
            get
            {
                return _length;
            }
        }
        public VectorType VectorType
        {
            get
            {
                return _vectorType;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Indexers
        public T this[ulong index]
        {
            get
            {
                return _data[index];
            }
            set
            {
                _data[index] = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public Vector(VectorType vectorType, T[] data)
        {
            if (!((data is float[]) || (data is Complex[])))
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException("Data must be array of float or array of Complex");
            }
            _data = new T[_length = (ulong)data.Length];
            for (ulong i = 0; i < _length; i++)
            {
                _data[i] = data[i];
            }
            _vectorType = vectorType;
        }


        public Vector(VectorType vectorType, Vector<T> vector)
        {
            _data = new T[_length = vector.Length];
            for (ulong i = 0; i < _length; i++)
            {
                _data[i] = vector[i];
            }
            _vectorType = vectorType;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

            //Unity Matrix, this vector has 1/N everywhere
            public static Vector<float> e(VectorType vectorType, ulong length)
            {
                var data = new float[length];
                for (ulong i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    data[i] = (float)1 / length;
                }
                var vectorE = new Vector<float>(vectorType, data); 
                return vectorE;
            }

            public float Sum()
            {
                float sum = 0;
                if (_data is float[])
                {
                    sum = (_data as float[]).Sum();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_data is Complex[])
                    {
                        for (ulong i = 0; i < _length; i++)
                        {
                            sum += (float)
                                Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((_data[i] as Complex?).Value.Real, 2) +
                                          Math.Pow((_data[i] as Complex?).Value.Imaginary, 2));
                        }
                    }
                }
                return sum;
            }

            public bool CheckIfSochasitc()
            {
                return Math.Abs(Sum() - 1) < float.Epsilon;
            }

            public void Normalize()
            {
                var sum = Sum();

                if (_data is float[])
                {
                    for (ulong i = 0; i < _length; i++)
                    {
                        float x = ((float) _data[i])/sum;
                        _data[i] =  (T)x;
                    }
                }

            }

        #endregion

        #region Operators
        //I omitted the code inhere to avoid overload
        #endregion

        #region Fields

            private  ulong _length;
            private readonly VectorType _vectorType;
            private T[] _data;

        #endregion
    }

    public enum VectorType
    {
        Row,Column        
    }
```

My problem is that I have a generic array (if I can call it so) :

```
private T[] _data;
```

And I have the Normalize() method:

```
public void Normalize()
          {
             var sum = Sum();
             if (_data is float[])
             {
                for (ulong i = 0; i < _length; i++)
                {
                    //Here is the problem
                    _data[i] =  ((_data[i] as float?) / sum);
                }
             }
          }
```

This doesn't work saying `can't cast float to T` tried to search but couldn't find helpful aide, any clarification I'd be thankful.

**Update :**

The Sum() method always returns a float

Comment: Generally it's an indication that you're probably not doing things well if this is a requirement.

Comment: Yeah sorry @dasblinkenlight yeah my french doesn't wanna leave me in peace, I update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear why you're converting to `float?` at all (or why you're using `ulong` as the index variable type...) but you just need to cast the result back to `T` - otherwise you can't assign it back into an array of type `T[]`. Additionally, you need to cast to `object` (in order to convert back to `T`:

```
float x = ((float) (object) data[i]) / sum;
data[i] = (T) (object) x;
```

You *can* use `float?` for the first line, with `as`, to avoid boxing - but then you need to get the non-nullable value:

```
float x = (data[i] as float?).Value / sum;
```

Both are pretty ugly :(

As noted in comments though, this sort of thing is usually an indication of the design not really being properly generic at all. We don't know what type `Sum()` returns, but you should consider just how "general" your type is to start with.

Comment: On the other hand, having code in a generic type that deals with specific types seems like incorrect design to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet I used the float? because of the as operator, Sum() returns a float always, I tried your coded : float x = ((float) data[i]) / sum;
 but the compiler still telling me Can't convert T to float

Comment: @AymenDaoudi: I don't follow your reasoning at all - and what's the compile-time type of `Sum()`? If it's float, then the code I've given should be fine. It would really help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @AymenDaoudi: Actually, I see the problem now - editing.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added your update, indeed the error at the line : 
float x = (data[i] as float?).Value / sum; has gone but still indicating a possible InvalideOperation exception, can you explain and advice me about that, also please since I posted the whole code, how should I design this class to avoid these problems. thx a lot

Comment: @Aymen: I can't right now, but your program still isn't complete... It's not full enough for me to run it and reproduce the error.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well I understand, the errors are gone for good now, although I didn't get them when running , it was at compile time, I'd still be thankful if you give me some advice about the generic implementation I made in the Class Vector, Thx again Jon

Comment: @Aymen: InvalidOperationException is not a compile-time error... Again, I don't have time to look right now. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: @JonSkeet okey thank you very very much I will wait for you advice when you have time sir :)

Answer (score -2):

May be you can try this

```
if (typeof(_data) == float[])
             {
                for (ulong i = 0; i < _length; i++)
                {
                    _data[i] =  ((_data[i] as float?) / sum);
                }
             }
```